# Use SearchView with android 2.3

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm trying to use a searchView in my app and i initialized the searcView (from android.support.v7.widget) like this in the onCreateOptionsMenu method (I use android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity and )

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_carte, menu);
    SupportMenuItem searchItem = (SupportMenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_recherche);
    searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    if (mSearchView != null) {
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
    setupSearchView(searchItem);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I'have not issues on android 4.4 but in android 2.3 I have this error :

Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is caused by png processor in gradle plugin. If you are using android studio change the gradle plugin to 0.9.2. This worked for me

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67388